# How can i get all instance guid's runnig on my app service in Azure using powershelll?

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a number of instance running under my app service in Azure. I need to get back all the id's of these instances.

I am currently using

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType 
Microsoft.Web/sites/instances -Name $WebAppName -ApiVersion 2016-03-01
```

But is there an equivalent command using the az cmdlets ?

Answer (score 0):

*I've tried the exact PowerShell command that you executed in Azure PowerShell. I could be able to get the expected results as shown:*

[image]

I've tried to get the desired outcome with `AZ cmdlet`(Bash) and received the expected results using:

```
az webapp list-instances
```

***To get the instances running info with their respective ID's on app service in Azure***:

```
az configure --defaults group=xxxxResourceGroupName
az configure --defaults web=xxxxwebapp
az webapp list-instances --name xxxxwebappp --resource-group xxxxResourceGroupName
```

[image]

*If you want to retrieve "default hostname, EnabledHostName as well as state" of WebApp, Use below command as shown*:

[image]

Refer MSDoc [az.webapp cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-list-instances)

Comment: Keeps giving the error: az : az webapp: 'list-instances' is not in the 'az webapp' command group

Comment: Did you set up Az login with your subscription? Hope you are trying in Azure CLI only!

Comment: You can [check this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/8565) for your az webapp issue if required.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to use latest `Az` PowerShell module cmdlets instead of `AzureRM` since `AzureRm` is going to retire soon.

In the above answer shared by @jahanvi replace `Get-AzureRMResource` with `Get-AzResource` which is a relevant Az module cmdlet.

Alternatively, you can use the [Azure Management RestAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-instance-identifiers#code-try-0) to get the list of instances running under a particular webapp using `Invoke-RequestMethod` you call the rest api from powershell as well.

**Here is the sample script:**

```
Connect-AzAccount
$context=Set-AzContext -Subscription "<subscriptionId>"
$token = Get-AzAccessToken
$authHeader=@{
    'Content-Type'='application/json'
    'Authorization'='Bearer '+ $token.Token
}
$instances=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<WebAppName>/instances?api-version=2022-03-01 -Method GET -Headers $authHeader
$instances.value.id
```

**Here is the sample screenshot for reference:**

[image]

Comment: From the above can we get the list of processes and the machine name ? Also can we restart a particular instance by instance name via powershell ?

Comment: @Tracey - instead of `$instances.value.id` if you project the output of `$instance.value` then you will be able to get the list of instances name & their respective ID and kudu console uri's. If you want to list the instance process, then you need to use this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-instance-processes)