# Find out why azure App service restarted itself and new instance replacing it

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I got the following message from my azure app service

"your application was recycled as there was a movement of your application from an existing worker instance because Azure platform detected that the worker instance was not working as expected. This resulted in your application being provisioned and started on a new VM instance. To reduce the impact of such events on your application, consider using the Application Initialization feature and ensure you are scaled to multiple workers."

The question is, is there anyway for us to find out why the "worker instance is not working as expected"? I tried to go to the azure app insight and can't find anything meaningful. thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
"your application was recycled as there was a movement of your application from an existing worker instance because Azure platform detected that the worker instance was not working as expected. This resulted in your application being provisioned and started on a new VM instance. To reduce the impact of such events on your application, consider using the Application Initialization feature and ensure you are scaled to multiple workers."
```

***One of the reason, Application recycling might happen when there were multiple startup failures causing worker recycle to be initiated from back end.***

Also, Refer the answer by **SnehaAgrawal-MSFT**  in the link below:-

[Azure infrastructure bug: automatic restart of App Service without graceful shutdown - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1183380/azure-infrastructure-bug-automatic-restart-of-app)

To get the current container logs, Call the Rest API below which will include all the container runtime logs including your worker
and startup logs:-

```http
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/containerlogs/zip/download?api-version=2022-03-01
```

If your application is recycled, It will be moved  to a healthy worker instance. If you want to know which worker is serving the live traffic, You can check Live metrics in Application insights connected to your Web app like below:-

[image]

***Select your Web app > Diagnose and Solve Problems > Availability and Performance > Select Web app down and Web app restarted option > In the Diagnostic Report check the name of the worker instance that failed.***

[image]

If your web app down insight says, The web app was restarted you can check the Web app restart option like below:-

[image]

You can **check the affected worker instance** by clicking on **Application Logs** like below:-

[image]

You can enable Health check in your Azure App service so the health check will ping the instances every 5-10 mins and remove the faulty instances and restart your web app for continuity of your application, Refer below:-

[image]

You can also enable Auto heal so whenever any instance is faulty, Your web app will be restarted or any action that you want will be performed refer below:-

[image]

Another way to list the Web app instances that is active is to run this Powershell command below:-

**Code:-**

```bash
Connect-AzAccount
$context=Set-AzContext -Subscription "<subscriptionId>"
$token = Get-AzAccessToken
$authHeader=@{
    'Content-Type'='application/json'
    'Authorization'='Bearer '+ $token.Token
}
$instances=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<WebAppName>/instances?api-version=2022-03-01 -Method GET -Headers $authHeader
$instances.value.id
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Diagnostics and solve tool - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics)

[powershell - How can i get all instance guid's runnig on my app service in Azure using powershelll? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74340759/how-can-i-get-all-instance-guids-runnig-on-my-app-service-in-azure-using-powers#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20instances%20running%20info%20with%20their,web%3Dxxxxwebapp%20az%20webapp%20list-instances%20--name%20xxxxwebappp%20--resource-group%20xxxxResourceGroupName)

[Web Apps - Get Container Logs Zip - REST API (Azure App Service) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get-container-logs-zip)

Comment: Great grab-bag for the sprawl of possible solutions to possible things that could go wrong there. Saving for my future sanity.